# retrieving data from firebase in my app and the data is manually uploaded

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to Retrieve data available on Firebase realtime Database to Recycler View, in which I have  uploaded data Manually. 
My Database contains Title column in which book name is present and Book column  in which url of book pdf is present and the book pdf is available on Firebase Storage .
The Application is like , User can accesss the book available on the Database by using search bar or mannually searching. I had not written code for the Search bar .

```
Adapter Code:-
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
Context c;

public MyAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<Model> models){
    this.c = c;
    this.models = models;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.
from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_list,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder , int position){
    holder.nameText.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fileimage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return models.size();
}
}






Two Layouts:-
1.main_activity

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp">
</SearchView>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>






2.book_list

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Name:"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>







Main_Activity:-
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ArrayList<Model> model;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


   databaseReference.child("Data").addValueEventListener(new                     
       ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            model=new ArrayList<>();

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Log.v("TAG","For Loop Entered");

                Model m = ds.getValue(Model.class);
                model.add(m);
            }

            Log.v("TAG","For Loop Closed");

            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,model);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.v("TAG","Read Error",databaseError.toException());

        }
    });
    }
}


MOdel Class:-
public class Model {

private String Title;
private String Book;

public Model(){

}

public Model(String Title , String Book){
    this.Title = Title;
    this.Book = Book;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.Title = title;
}

public String getBook() {
    return Book;
}

public void setBookName(String Book) {
    this.Book = Book;
}


}


Database Structure image:-


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6tQH.png




https://book-shelf-364b7.firebaseio.com/
 book-shelf-364b7
   Data
     Book:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boo..."
     Title:"CPP"
```

Comment: 2 questions: Are you getting any errors? Can you post the code for your `Model.class`?

Comment: Please add the database structure and the content of your `Model.class` and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Yeah sure.I have post the model class you can check it now @AlexMamo

Comment: Please see the duplicate and please also don't use that for loop.